# Is my tomato ketchup safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety

I pressure cooked my tomato ketchup for 10 min, then simmered for 12 hours (internal temp 150 degrees).This was lower that I intended. Is it safe to now freeze it in small containers?

Answer (score 4):

It was safe  to consume after the pressure cooking.  It was safe to consume after the simmering. It will be safe to consume from the refrigerator or freezer.  You might want to edit your question to explain what you did with it after simmering and before freezing.